# Error "Incorrect syntax near '@part1' sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to make a dynamic stored procedure.
Here is the initial code

```
Declare @sqlstrsel as nvarchar(max) ;
Declare @cols as nvarchar(max) ;
Declare @tables as nvarchar(max) ;
Declare @condt as nvarchar(max) ;
Set @cols='*'
Set @tables='products'
Set @condt=''
Set @sqlstrsel = 'select ' + @cols+ 'from ' +@table +@condt
Exec (@sqlstrsel)
```

This code works fine, but when changed to a stored procedure like below

```
Alter proc selectT

@cols  nvarchar(max) ;
@tables nvarchar(max) ;
@condt nvarchar(max) ;
As
Begin 
Declare @sqlstrsel as nvarchar(max) ;
Set @sqlstrsel = 'select ' + @cols+ 'from ' +@table +@condt
Exec (@sqlstrsel);
End
```

When I execute this proc in a new query, by providing the parameters,

```
Set @par1='*'
Set @par2= 'products'
Set @par3 =''
Exec selectT(@par1,@par2,@par3)
```

I get two errors
Procedure or function 'selectt' expect parameter '@cols which was not provided,
And
Incorrect syntax near' @par1'
Par1 to the par 3 are declared beforehand.

Comment: Stored proc execute syntax is `EXEC selectT @par1,@par2,@par3` (no parenthesis).

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Is this simply a minimal example to demonstrate your issue, or are you planning on incorporating this code as-is into an actual application?

Comment: @alroc thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: I am looking into how to prevent sql injection, thanks